# Merge local Backbone collection with server

Tags: backbone.js, collections, models

I have a local Backbone collection:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([ { greeting: "hi" }, { greeting: "bye" } ]);
```

I understand that when I run `collection.fetch`, Backbone will run `collection.set` on the results. I need to merge in the response from the server, however. Say the response is:

```
[ { id: "2", greeting: "hi", name: "Bob" } ]
```

I would like the resulting collection, after the merge, to be:

```
[ { id: "2", greeting: "hi", name: "Bob" }, { greeting: "bye" } ]
```

I understand Backbone already attempts to do some merging here, but if I `set` the example response above, no merge happens and a new model gets added instead. I assume this is because it merges by `id`, and here we do not have any `id`s (in the local collection). In this case, `greeting` is my unique identifier / key.

The reason I am trying to do this is because I have a local collection and I simply want to see what already exists from that collection (using the key `greeting`) and merge any findings in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
feeds.fetch({
  add: false,
  remove: false,
  merge: false,
  data: params,
  success: function (feeds, response) {
    // Merge any matches
    _.each(response.results, function (result) {
      _.each(feeds.models, function (feed) {
        // We have to `parse` the result before setting it, as Model#set does
        // not automatically run `parse` (Collection#set does).
        result = feed.parse(result)
        if (feed.get('rssUrl') === result.rssUrl) feed.set(result)
      })
    })
    cb(feeds)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell backbone to use a different key for the id attribute on your model:

```
GreetingModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "greeting"
});

GreetingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: GreetingModel
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

**Edit:** I suppose you could use two separate collections for local and server side.

```
var localCollection = new Backbone.Collection([ { greeting: "hi" }, { greeting: "bye" } ]);

ServerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/api/"
  ...
});

var serverCollection = new ServerCollection({});

serverCollection.on("reset", function() {   
    localCollection.each(function(localModel) {
        var greeting = localModel.get("greeting");
        serverModel = serverCollection.findWhere({greeting: greeting});
        if(serverModel) {
            localModel.set(serverModel.attributes);          
        } 
    });
});

serverCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: I still want to keep the `idAttribute` as `id` for all other purposes.